# Why do magnetic forces scale down so poorly?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, nanoscience, magnetostatics

Im told by experts in MEMS and nanotech that magnetic forces scale down very poorly. This is one reason we have many MEMS devices based on electric forces/electrostatics but not on magnetics.

Can anyone explain why these magnetic forces scale down so poorly, or why they aren't as prominent of the nano and mesoscale?